# Sign fluctuation in the harmonic series (sum)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Lets begin with a few simple rules that we know.

-$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}=\infty$

-$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\color{red}{(}-1\color{red}{)}^{n-1}}{n}= \ln2 $

Going off of this knowledge, we know two things: A normal sum of a harmonic series is not equal to a number and/or is divergent. Secondly, a divergent series can have a constant solution as long as it goes back and forth between positive terms and negative terms in a fairly regular way.

What about this related summation?

$$\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{10}\cdots$$

The terms for the series are the same, but there is a funky pattern with their signs. If you just looked at the signs this is what you would see: +--+++----...

This sum must diverge, by nature. But I feel that this sum is < $\infty$. However, this conjecture is 100% intuition, and I really don't know where to start. This leads to our question:

Is the summation < $\infty$? (A proof or disproof is wonderful) If the summation happens to be < \infty what does it sum to (technically)? Thank you so much!

Comment: Some lectures here. 

http://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/335_14/history%20of%20rearrangements.pdf

http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_zaboronski/analysisi/rr_theorem.pdf

Comment: Am I interpreting the pattern right, you want $k$ signs of one type, followed by $k+1$ signs of the other type? So $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{\sigma(n)}{n},$$ where $\sigma(n) = (-1)^{k+1}$ if $\frac{k(k-1)}{2} < n \leqslant \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$?

Comment: After a more careful reading of your question, I see that [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753960/convergence-of-alternating-harmonic-series-where-sign-is-etc?rq=1) addresses convergence. (I'm rather sure that a closed form is hopeless)