# Dirichlet's Test in convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Can Dirichlet's test be applied to establish the convergence of 
$1 - \frac 1 2 - \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 4 + \frac 1 5 + \frac 1 6 - \dots$
where the number of signs increase by one in each block?

Can somebody give me some ideas or hints?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753960/convergence-of-alternating-harmonic-series-where-sign-is-etc?rq=1

Comment: @DanielFischer What does one do when the question's closed but there's a "good" answer missing? To wit: Although Dirichlet's test does not apply, the _proof_ of Dirichlet works! (If $\epsilon_j$ is the sequence of plus and minus ones then the $n$th partial sum of $\epsilon_j$ is $O(\sqrt n)$. Hence summation by parts works. Moral: proofs of theorems are better than theorems...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Answer at the duplicate target, that isn't closed. (And that answer would be sure to get an upvote from me.)

Comment: Note that the duplicate thread has a new and much improved answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Convergence of the Extreme Subsequence**

Dirichlet does not apply to the series as written. However, if we rewrite the series, collecting the runs of positive and negative terms, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left[\sum_{k=\frac{n^2-n+2}2}^{\frac{n^2+n}2}\frac1k\right]
$$
and using the asymptotic expansion $H_n=\gamma+\log(n)+O\left(\frac1n\right)$
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=\frac{n^2-n+2}2}^{\frac{n^2+n}2}\frac1k
&=\log\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2-n}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\
&=\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac2n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Now, we can use Dirichlet
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\left[\frac2n+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)\right]
=\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac2n}_{\text{Dirichlet applies}}+\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)}_{\text{$p$-test applies}}
$$

---

**Convergence of the Subsequence Implies Convergence in This Case**

As David Ullrich comments, by grouping terms, we are only computing a subsequence of the partial sums. However, since we've grouped consecutive positives together and consecutive negatives together, filling in the full sequence of partial sums simply adds values between the values in our subsequence. For example,
$$
1-\frac12-\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16-\frac17-\frac18-\frac19-\frac1{10}+\frac1{11}+\frac1{12}
$$
is between
$$
1-\frac12-\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16-\frac17-\frac18-\frac19-\frac1{10}
$$
and
$$
1-\frac12-\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16-\frac17-\frac18-\frac19-\frac1{10}+\frac1{11}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{13}+\frac1{14}+\frac1{15}
$$
Therefore, we are computing "extreme" partial sums between which the full sequence of partial sums "bounce", so the full sequence of partial sums will converge as well.

---

**Evaluation Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula**

In the first section, we used the asymptotic expansion $H_n=\gamma+\log(n)+O\left(\frac1n\right)$ to determine that the series converges.  Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, we can go further:
$$
\small H_n=\gamma+\log(n)+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}-\frac1{252n^6}+\frac1{240n^8}-\frac1{132n^{10}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{12}}\right)
$$
From this, we can compute the asymptotic series
$$
\begin{align}
\small g(n)\ 
&\small=H_{\frac{n^2+n}2}-H_{\frac{n^2-n}2}\\
&\small=\frac2n-\frac4{3n^3}-\frac4{15n^5}+\frac{20}{21n^7}+\frac{52}{45n^9}-\frac{20}{11n^{11}}-\frac{9644}{1365n^{13}}\\[6pt]
&\small+\frac{116}{45n^{15}}+\frac{5076}{85n^{17}}+\frac{38564}{665n^{19}}-\frac{2275804}{3465n^{21}}-\frac{654044}{345n^{23}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{25}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Then, we can compute
$$
\begin{align}
\small h(n)\ 
&\small=g(2n-1)-g(2n)\\
&\small=\frac1{2n^2}+\frac1{4n^3}-\frac1{8n^4}-\frac3{16n^5}-\frac{19}{96n^6}-\frac{11}{64n^7}-\frac{43}{384n^8}-\frac{41}{768n^9}+\frac{27}{2560n^{10}}\\
&\small+\frac{69}{1024n^{11}}+\frac{677}{6144n^{12}}+\frac{557}{4096n^{13}}+\frac{38797}{286720n^{14}}+\frac{26107}{245760n^{15}}+\frac{4597}{98304n^{16}}\\
&\small-\frac{2627}{65536n^{17}}-\frac{838061}{5898240n^{18}}-\frac{316167}{1310720n^{19}}-\frac{1130847}{3670016n^{20}}-\frac{6769583}{22020096n^{21}}\\
&\small-\frac{23505703}{115343360n^{22}}+\frac{616009}{20971520n^{23}}+\frac{29333183}{75497472n^{24}}+\frac{68957009}{83886080n^{25}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{26}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Apply the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to get
$$
\begin{align}
\small k(n)\ 
&\small=-\frac1{2n}+\frac1{8n^2}+\frac1{12n^3}-\frac5{64n^4}+\frac1{240n^5}+\frac{11}{384n^6}-\frac5{1344 n^7}-\frac{151}{6144n^8}\\
&\small-\frac{13}{11520n^9}+\frac{507}{10240n^{10}}+\frac5{11264n^{11}}-\frac{6797}{49152n^{12}}+\frac{2411}{5591040n^{13}}+\frac{623927}{1146880n^{14}}\\
&\small-\frac{29}{737280n^{15}}-\frac{9105847}{3145728n^{16}}-\frac{1269}{5570560n^{17}}+\frac{470568199}{23592960n^{18}}-\frac{9641}{174325760n^{19}}\\
&\small-\frac{25364768763}{146800640n^{20}}+\frac{568951}{3633315840n^{21}}+\frac{848095747927}{461373440n^{22}}+\frac{163511}{1447034880n^{23}}\\
&\small-\frac{142300201072307}{6039797760 n^{24}}+O\left(\frac1{n^{25}}\right)
\end{align}
$$
Then, finally,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{32}(-1)^{n-1}\left[\sum_{k=\frac{n^2-n+2}2}^{\frac{n^2+n}2}\frac1k\right]-k(16)=0.51710037904240172506
$$

Comment: Here and in that other thread we solutions that establish the convergence of a _subsequence_ of the partial sums. In this case getting from there to convergence of the partial sums is not hard. But it seems like one should at least mention the issue, lest someone get the idea that "regrouping" is always "allowed", which then shows that, say, $\sum(-1)^n$ converges.

Comment: That's true.  I must consider how to best present the fact that since we've grouped the positives and negatives, any intermediate partial sum is actually between the corresponding partial sums in this subsequence.

Comment: I think now that pretty well shows that the full sequence of partial sums converges.

Comment: Pretty welll, yeah. Of course it seems to me that just doing the thing by summation by parts is simpler. (See my new answer in the duplicate thread - couldn't put it here, got here too late...)

Comment: They're both fine approaches. Although I stopped at $O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$, the sum of each block turns out to be $\frac2n-\frac4{3n^3}+O\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: however, using this method allows us to compute the sum to $20$ places using $528$ terms in the original series. This is pretty good considering that using $1000000$ terms in the original series, without the correction from the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, gives $3$ places.

Comment: There is that. Of course we're shifting those goalposts...

Comment: Yeah, but I thought it might be interesting for someone.

Comment: Oh, it was interesting to me...

Answer (score 0):

Dirichlet's test does not apply directly, since partial sums of the series generated by $(-1, -1, 1, 1, \dots)$ are not bounded.